# Nvidia 1050 GPU , unable to install drivers on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia

I'm trying to install Nvidia drivers for a Nvidia GTX 1050 GPU on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04. However, I have been unsuccessful. 
Thus far, I have followed [this guide](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux) (steps 1 - 5) to install the drivers on a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 installation. However, it shows no driver for the GPU:

```
lshw -c video
 WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
*-display UNCLAIMED     
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: NVIDIA Corporation
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller cap_list
   configuration: latency=0    //SHOULD SAY driver=... here
   resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000
```

[In the Additional Drivers menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbl7V.jpg), it appears as though Nvidia-387 is installed.

I've tried installing Nvidia-375, and 384 as well with the same results.

Additional outputs:

```
$ lsmod | fgrep nvidia       //no output
$ lsmod | fgrep nouveau      //no output
$
```

Any suggestions on how I might get drivers successfully installed would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried following the suggestion in the warning (`sudo lshw -c video` instead)? Also, your question is unclear. You seem to be asking both what's going on with `lshw` not showing the driver used and how to install a driver.

Comment: I'm asking how to install the driver, and providing some information about the current state of the installation. I edited for clarity. I tried with sudo, and same result.

Comment: Ahh, OK. Does `sudo lshw -c video` still omit the driver?

Comment: Yes it's still omitted.

Comment: Which steps in that guide did you follow? 1 through 6, 1 through 7, something else?

Comment: 1 through 5, at which point it was clear something was off.   (:

Comment: I wouldn't follow that guide for Linux. I would use the software built into Ubuntu Software Settings -> Software Updates & Additional Drivers -> Additional Drivers -> nVidia 384. This worked good for me under a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install until I broke the system later. Also what kind of computer do you have? Setup can be more complicated with certain laptops.

Comment: That's what I'm confused about - the additional drivers window shows that NVIDIA binary driver - version 387.34 is in use (link in post). However, clinfo shows 0 devices, and the output provided above shows no drivers for the graphics card.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in UEFI settings otherwise even when installed unsigned drivers won't load.